# Why isn't search working on the live page?

Tags: templating, search

I have search working on my local .dev site.   It does not work on my live hosted site.  There are no error messages; it just reloads the home page.

Here is the search code in my site template.  The results code is below...

```
<li class="menu-item-search">
    <a href="search.html"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    <form method="get" id="site-searchform" class="searchform" action="{{ url('search/results')}}">
        <input type="search" name="q" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search&hellip;">
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
</li>
```

The results page...

```
<main id="content" class="cointainer container-masonry" role="main"> 
    <div id="grid-fix" class="container">

        {% if entries|length %}     
            {% for post in entries %}
                <div class="box col-sm-3">
                    <div class="post-box vertical clearfix">

                        <div class="extra-info">                
                            <h5><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title}}</a></h5>
                            <p class="meta small">{{ post.postDate | date('F d, Y') }} <a href="#">Name</a></p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}    
        {% else %}
            <p>You search for "{{ query }}" didn't retun any results</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</main>
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: You're not getting sent to `yoursite.com/search/results`?

Comment: The problem appears to be with the "{{ url('search/results') }}".  I can hard code it as "http://mysite.com/search/results" and it works.  For some reason, Craft/Twig is not printing the first part of the url.

Comment: Probably an issue with how your siteUrl is defined (either in CP under Settings->General) or in your `craft/config/general.php` file.